# Sending multiple resquest from a loop asynchronously

Tags: node.js

I'm working on an application which have to read excel files and send each line  to a server;

Now I would like to do it asynchronously, I mean I would like to get the result of `server.postRequest(1);` before sending another request `server.postRequest(2);`

```
for (let row = 2; row <= nrows; row++) {
    Excel.mapExcelLine(workbook.Sheets[firstSheetName], row, ncols)
    .then((data) => {
        let idExcel = data.id;
        database.get("SELECT * FROM sync WHERE idExcel=?", [idExcel], async function (err, row) {
            if (row == undefined) {
                let promise = await server.postRequest(row.id);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the `postRequest` function

```
postRequest(id){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        options.body = id;
        request.post(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (response.headers['msg'] == 'authrequired') {
                 request.post(authOptions, function (error, response, body) {
                       if(response.headers['msg'] == 'ok')
                           postRequest(id);
                       else resolve(402);
                 });
            }
            else if(response.headers['msg'] == 'ok'){
                 logger.info('Demand' + id + 'created'
                 resolve(200);    
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Now when I'm trying to loop through this array for example:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

messages from postResquest function don't appear in the right order.

How to wait for each request to finish before sending another one ?

the expected output is:

```
Demand 1 created
Demand 2 created
Demand 3 created
Demand 4 created
```

Comment: You are looking for [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). It resolves the promises in order they are passed in

Comment: Promise.all does not guarantee order of execution

Comment: Check `p-series` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-series) which suits this use case.

Answer (score 0):

You must use await for the requests you are sending asynchronously